# GANs output is not optimum

Tags: python, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement GANs for super-resolution enhancement using Tensorflow. Here is the link of my collab code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F376Y6T5ehoE-mk2q7LGBmLq-OkWxqtr?usp=sharing
[image: The ground truth iamge]

[image: the expected image]

First image is the output image

Second is the Expected output

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong in the image. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your generator looks quite simple. Try adding some more convolutional layers `Conv2D` after upsampling the inputs. There are also many techniques & architectures (such as **Pix2Pix**) that handle very well high quality images.

This repository contains quite a few GANs that might help you improve your model + some tricks You can do to improve the overall quality:
https://github.com/kochlisGit/Keras-GAN